# I want to crate a Django field in my model to display a word after each new entry

Tags: python, django

So I want to create a field in my Django models.py, so that the user can select a number of years as integer (e.g. 3) and then after each new entry the words 'years' to be automatically displayed. I do not want to do this with CharField.

```
class StudyProgramme(models.Model):
    period = models.IntegerField(2)
```

Comment: I don't understand your question; you should just put "years" in the template when you output this field, surely?

Comment: I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a serializer for the same.

```
from rest_framework import serializers

class StudyProgrammeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_period(self, obj):
        return str(obj.period) + "years" 

    class Meta:
        model = StudyProgramme
        fields = ['period']
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't get it yet but i think you can do it like:

```
# Check the model StudyProgramme
If StudyProgramme.Objects.all().count() > 0: //Show
Else: //request to put it it
# And for sure, return it to template
```